# On AppFog or CloudFoundry, how can app update be forced?

Tags: django, cloud-foundry, appfog

I am deploying an Django/Python app on [AppFog](http://www.appfog.com) (which is based on [CloudFoundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/)). Until recently, updates could easily be deployed using the `af update`command. Here's an example:

consider a local file `settings.py` with some changes, e.g.:

```
  ...
  # CHANGES
  MY_SETTING = 'TEST'
  ...
```

Previously, when I issued `af update myapp`, waited until the app restartd and then look at the `settings.py` on the app instance (`af files myapp app/settings.py`), I would get back exactly the above, changed file.

Now all of a sudden, when I do the same steps, the changes are not applied. The restarted app always uses the old version of settings.py (and any other files that changed in between). I have tried to issue `af update myapp --no-resources` to force upload of all files, or to `af push` to a different app -- same result.

How can I force AppFog or CloudFoundry in general to drop whatever package it stores for my app and accept a fresh update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that specific files can be updated in one of two ways:

a) by giving the file name one by one:

```
af update myapp --path myfile.ext
```

b) by creating a zip file

```
zip /tmp/update.zip file1 file2 file3
af update myapp --path /tmp/update.zip
```

While the first approach will update the specific text file, the second will update all the files contained in the zip file.

**Note of caution:** If your source path contains a .zip or .war file, the `af` command will *always* use this .zip or .war file as the source for its update. See the [code](https://github.com/appfog/af/blob/master/lib/cli/commands/apps.rb#L514) for details.